# Не удается установить модель на opencart 2.2

Tags: opencart, импорт, модули, export

Добрый день друзья, не могу установить модель на opencart 2.2. Установку произвожу через установщик расширений, пытаюсь установить модуль для экспорта/импорта файлов. Выдает ошибки в файле install.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за модуль? Другие модули устанавливаются? FTP в настройках включен, настроен, работает?

Comment: на хосте права на папки выставьте 750

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ уже решил проблему